# Why does MongoDB $size returns 1 for an empty sub-array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Given a MongoDB collection in the following structure

```
{
"_id" : 1,
"system_id" : "123",
"sub_systems" : [
    {
        "sub_system_id" : "456",
        "status" : "connected",
        "messages_relayed" : [ ] // An array of message_ids that have been relayed
    }
]}
```

I'd like to create a query to return how many messages have been relayed by each *sub_system*. I started with this:

```
db.messages.aggregate([{
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "num_of_msgs_relayed": {
                "$cond":
                    {"if": { "$isArray": "$sub_systems.messages_relayed" },
                        "then": { "$size": "$sub_systems.messages_relayed" },
                        "else": 0}
            }}}]);
```

To my surprise, the result is:

> { "num_of_msgs_relayed" : 1 }

**QUESTION**: I expected the query to return a 0 value, since basically I'm projecting the $*size* of an empty array! What is the reasoning behind this 1?

<sub>P.S.: The following command can be used to create the data shown on *messages* collection:</sub>

> db.runCommand(    {
>         insert: "messages",
>         documents: [{'_id': 1, 'system_id': '123', 'sub_systems':[{'status': 'connected', 'messages_relayed': []}]}]    }
>   )

Comment: `$unwind` then `$group` with `$sum`.  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the simplest query below to observe how MongoDB interprets `sub_systems.messages_relayed`:

```
db.messages.aggregate([
    { "$project": { "arr": "$sub_systems.messages_relayed"}}
]);
```

So this query will return an array of arrays since `sub_systems` is one outer array and `messages_relayed` is another one. That's why you're getting `1` instead of `0`

To "project the size of empty array" you should use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) before your project and below aggregation will return `0` instead of `1`

```
db.messages.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$sub_systems" },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      num_of_msgs_relayed: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $isArray: "$sub_systems.messages_relayed" },
          then: { $size: "$sub_systems.messages_relayed" },
          else: 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```